# How to parse a JSON data with JSON object & JSON array from service to a sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm trying to get data from service to store in a local sqlite database on device when first time android app is installed. But the app on debugging gives fatal exception in async task in logcat and app closes abruptly. Any help with explanation will do, I'm still learning android development. Below is my code & service for reference, Thanks. Please help further how can I store this data in a local sqlite database.

JSON response from service:

```
{"GetData":[{"Email":"hans@gmail.com",
"FirstName":"Hansel",
"GroupName":"FB",
"HomeAddress":"E-8\/9, UGF, Second Suite, NY",
"ID":"hans@gmail.com",
"LastName":"Gretel",
"MobileNumbers":["+128990068","+12399884"],
"Name":"Hansel Gretel",
"OfficeAddress":"D-82, Second Floor, London Boulevard, NJ",
"TelephoneNumbers":["01312300534","+128790084"]},

{"Email":"ishyk@gmail.com",
"FirstName":"Airina",
"GroupName":"FB",
"HomeAddress":"E-8\/9, UGF, Second Suite, NY",
"ID":"ishyk@gmail.com",
"LastName":"Shyk",
"MobileNumbers":["+1 (287) 304-5115","+1 (285) 304-5115"],
"Name":"Airina Shyk",
"OfficeAddress":"D-82, Third Floor, London Boulevard, NJ",
"TelephoneNumbers":["+1 (125) 367-6085","+1 (125) 367-6087"]}]}
```

My MainActivity class:

```
package com.fb.jsondata;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://fb.mysite.com/CDService/CDService.svc/GetMyData///johndow@gmail.com";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "GetData";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    private static final String TAG_FIRST_NAME = "FirstName";
    private static final String TAG_LAST_NAME = "LastName";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String TAG_HOME_ADDRESS = "HomeAddress";
    private static final String TAG_OFFICE_ADDRESS = "OfficeAddress";
    private static final String TAG_GROUP_NAME = "GroupName";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "TelephoneNumbers";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "MobileNumbers";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // mobile JSONArray
    JSONArray mobiles = null;

    // telephone JSONArray
    JSONArray telephones = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    ArrayList<String> myMob;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_HOME_ADDRESS);
                        String address1 = c.getString(TAG_OFFICE_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GROUP_NAME);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        mobiles = c.getJSONArray(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);                        
                        for(int n=0;n<mobiles.length();n++)
                        {
                              String mobile = (String) mobiles.get(n);
                              myMob.add(mobile);
                        }

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, myMob.toString());

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                            TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Service handler class:

```
package com.fb.jsondata;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

Logcat response:

```
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.bnk.jsondata.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:160)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.bnk.jsondata.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-06 17:41:27.980: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  ... 4 more
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362): Activity com.bnk.jsondata.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f61928 that was originally added here
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.bnk.jsondata.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f61928 that was originally added here
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at com.bnk.jsondata.MainActivity$GetContacts.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:109)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at com.bnk.jsondata.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-06 17:41:30.931: E/WindowManager(362):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've added the logcat, have a look.

Comment: post the logcat error response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm surprised you won't get nullpointerexception...as you haven't initialize the myMob ArrayList....
I recommend you to initialize the ArrayList myMob first ...and then see the result..

Answer (score 0):

I can see a **ClassCastException** in your Logs at

```
for(int n=0;n<mobiles.length();n++)
  {
    String mobile = (String) mobiles.get(n);
    myMob.add(mobile);
  }
```

Use `mobiles.getString(n)` instead. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @santoshavss, I tried it but no any progress.